# Android Key Store doesn't decrypt passsword

Tags: android, aes, password-encryption, android-keystore

I learning the cryptography in Android. Try to encrypt/decrypt user's password. Encryption method is working pretty fine, but decryption method is always getting me an error.

Here is code of the CryptoManager class:

```
package edu.xfoleks.komodoro.presentation.utils

import android.security.keystore.KeyProperties
import android.security.keystore.KeyProtection
import android.util.Base64
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets
import java.security.KeyStore
import java.util.Calendar
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec

class CryptoManager {

    init {
        generateSecretKey()
    }
    private fun generateSecretKey() {

        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE).apply {
            load(null)
        }

        val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM).apply {
            init(KEY_SIZE)
        }

        val secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey()

        val startTime = Calendar.getInstance()
        val expireTime = Calendar.getInstance().apply {
            add(Calendar.YEAR, 2)
        }

        val entry = KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey)
        val protectionParameter =
            KeyProtection.Builder(KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setKeyValidityStart(startTime.time)
                .setKeyValidityEnd(expireTime.time)
                .setBlockModes(BLOCK_MODE)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(PADDING)
                .build()

        keyStore.setEntry(ALIAS, entry, protectionParameter)
    }

    fun encrypt(plainText: String): String {
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE).apply { load(null) }

        val secretKey = keyStore.getKey(ALIAS, null)

        return try {
            val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey)

            val cipherText = Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(plainText.toByteArray()), Base64.DEFAULT)
            val iv = Base64.encodeToString(cipher.iv, Base64.DEFAULT)

            "${cipherText}.$iv"

        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            ""
        }
    }

    fun decrypt(cipherText: String): String? {
        val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEY_STORE).apply { load(null) }

        val secretKey = keyStore.getKey(ALIAS, null)

        val array = cipherText.split(".")
        val cipherData = Base64.decode(array[0], Base64.DEFAULT)
        val iv = Base64.decode(array[1], Base64.DEFAULT)

        return try {
            val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
            val spec = IvParameterSpec(iv)

            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, spec)

            val clearText = cipher.doFinal(cipherData)

            val encoded = String(clearText, 0, clearText.size, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

            encoded
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
            null
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val KEY_STORE = "AndroidKeyStore"
        private const val KEY_SIZE = 256
        private const val ALIAS = "secret"
        private const val ALGORITHM = KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES
        private const val BLOCK_MODE = KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC
        private const val PADDING = KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7
        private const val TRANSFORMATION = "$ALGORITHM/$BLOCK_MODE/$PADDING"
    }
}
```

Classes, which working with decryption/encryption:

```
class LogInViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userInteractor: UserInteractor
) : ViewModel() {

    private var _user = MutableLiveData<UserInfoItem>()

    private fun decryptPassword(password: String): String? {
        val cryptoManager = CryptoManager()
        return cryptoManager.decrypt(password)
    }

    fun logIn(userName: String, password: String): Boolean {
        val user = UserInfoItem(userName, password)
        _user.value = user
        val existingUser = userInteractor.getUser(user.toUser()).toUserInfoItem()
        val decryptedPassword = decryptPassword(existingUser.password)

        return user.userName.equals(existingUser.userName) && user.password.equals(decryptedPassword)
    }
}
```

```
class RegistrationViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val userInteractor: UserInteractor
) : ViewModel() {

    private var _user = MutableLiveData<UserInfoItem>()

    private fun encryptPassword(password: String): String {
        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            throw EmptyPasswordException()
        }

        val cryptoManager = CryptoManager()
        return cryptoManager.encrypt(password)
    }

    fun registerUser(userName: String, password: String) {
        if (userName.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty()) { throw UserNotCreatedException() }
        val encryptedPassword = encryptPassword(password)
        val user = UserInfoItem(userName, encryptedPassword)
        _user.value = user
        userInteractor.registerUser(user.toUser())
    }

}
```

The error message:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:609)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056)
at edu.xfoleks.komodoro.presentation.utils.CryptoManager.decrypt(CryptoManager.kt:83)
at edu.xfoleks.komodoro.presentation.screens.viewmodels.LogInViewModel.decryptPassword(LogInViewModel.kt:22)
at edu.xfoleks.komodoro.presentation.screens.viewmodels.LogInViewModel.logIn(LogInViewModel.kt:29)
at edu.xfoleks.komodoro.presentation.screens.fragments.LogInFragment.onCreateView$lambda$5(LogInFragment.kt:47)
at edu.xfoleks.komodoro.presentation.screens.fragments.LogInFragment.$r8$lambda$NaDtgxEMrBbrOBDtRje0oMjYmGs(Unknown Source:0)
at edu.xfoleks.komodoro.presentation.screens.fragments.LogInFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid argument (internal Keystore code: -38 message: In KeystoreOperation::finish

Caused by:
0: In finish: KeyMint::finish failed.
1: Error::Km(ErrorCode(-38))) (public error code: 10 internal Keystore code: -38)
at android.security.KeyStore2.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore2.java:369)  
at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.handleExceptions(KeyStoreOperation.java:78)   
at android.security.KeyStoreOperation.finish(KeyStoreOperation.java:128)    
at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer$MainDataStream.finish(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:228)
at android.security.keystore2.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:181)
at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:603)
... 20 more
```

I had tried to save all settings for encryption and then use it for decryption, but it gave me nothing.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. A `BadPaddingException` usually occurs when decryption fails, e.g. due to a wrong key, a corrupted ciphertext, etc. Since you only posted the class definition, but not the control code, I can only speculate: Maybe you instantiate `CryptoManager` once for encryption and once for decryption. This would overwrite the key in the keystore, so that in the end different keys would be used for encryption and decryption, which would explain the issue.

Comment: @Topaco add classes which using this methods

Comment: Seems to be as already suspected, i.e. two different `CryptoManager` instances for encryption and decryption.

Comment: @Topaco i will try to add dependency into viewmodels

Comment: You should update you code and not generate a new key if the KeyStore already contains one.

Comment: @Robert, ok, I'll try it

Comment: I would go even further: Why generate a key at all during decryption?

Comment: @Topaco i saw this in some youtube tutorial. I understood that it could be not a best practice, but had tried anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the security of password we need to use hashing, not encryption/decryption. You can look up and implement algorithms like bcrypt, scrypt or Argon2.